# Haskell appears to be ignoring the closing ')' in a function call inside a function

Tags: haskell, syntax, compiler-construction

I'm doing homework for a class on haskell, and we are building an interpreter. the first set of functions is to evaluate variables,

```
evalE (Var x) s        = subEv (Map.lookup x s)
where subEv (Just a)   = a
      subEv (Nothing)  = (IntVal 0)
evalE (Val v) s       = v
evalE (Op o e1 e2) s  = (evalE e1 s) 'o' (evalE e2 s)
```

So, the first two versions work fine, the issue is on the third evalE, the compiler keeps interpreting the `(evalE e1 s) 'o' (evalE e2 s)` as if the `o` and `(evalE e2 s)` are being given as arguments to the `(evalE e1 s)`

I can't figure out why it is ignoring the existence of the first closing parenthesis, and I'm new to haskell so I can't see where any syntax errors are in that line. But regardless, the compiler won't compile and says there are too many arguments to evalE, and I'm losing patience fast since it doesn't seem like anything should be wrong. Am I completely missing something from here?

On further testing, the same issue appears anywhere within the code for evalE that a function is called (even functions that are not recursive seem to be ignoring the ')' )

Comment: Please, it's not "haskell" ignoring syntax, but your compiler, which is... ghc? hugs? nhc? yhc? - anyway, it's correct that "a b c" means "application of the function a to the arguments b and c" (where in your case "a" is the result of an expression).

Answer (score 5):

I assume that `o` is a two-argument function and you want to use it as an infix operator. Then you have to use backticks instead of single quotes (which are for character literals).

Try to change your last clause as follows:

```
evalE (Op o e1 e2) s  = (evalE e1 s) `o` (evalE e2 s)
```

To wrap up: `foo 'f' bar` means "call `foo` with character `'f'` and `bar` as the parameters", while `` foo `f` bar `` means "apply `f` to `foo` and `bar`".

So the compiler's behaviour was perfectly correct.

Comment: Thank you, that works, i didn't realize they needed backticks, my bad haha.